# R - How to find a mode of column data set?

Tags: r

I've approx. 75k data set. The file with data contains two columns: one with the `event_id` and the second with `prices`.(Prices are some real numbers) I've to find the mode (most frequent value) of the prices for each `event_id`. I have been trying to do that using this command:

```
aggregate(price~event_id,data=bets,FUN="mode")
```

but the value for each `event_id` is `numeric`. I haven't got any idea what does `numeric` means. Do you have? Or do you know any other way to find the mode of that kind of data set?

Thanks

Comment: "mode" is the "mode" of the variable, which is quantitative, thus numeric. If you want the mode (most frequent value) you can write a function.

Comment: So there is no option for doing it quickly? When I am replacing "mode" in my command by "mean" or "median" everything is fine and I still get right values. Have you got any examples of this function? I am pretty new in R.

Answer (score 1):

```
mode_fun <- function(x) {

     mode0 <- names(which.max(table(x)))

     if(is.numeric(x)) return(as.numeric(mode0))

     mode0

}

aggregate(price~event_id,data=bets,FUN=mode_fun)
```

Comment: Well, thaks a lot. It's working. How can I put it into a txt file?

Comment: You'd better make another question for that (different topic). You should also provide a reproducible example of what you ask. Anyway, have a look at: `?write.table`

Comment: Right, I do understand. I see that you have edited your answer. Now my R editor is saying that object 'x' is not found.

Comment: strange. On my laptop, it works. The modification just says that if the input is a numeric variable, like the one you have, the `class` of the output should be numeric too. However, if your purpose is to put your output on a text file and stop, the previous version of my code is also ok.

Comment: Last question. How am I suppose to know that is's actually finding the mode? Can you explain to me briefly how the line  names(which.max(table(x))) works?

Comment: you want to get the name (`names`) of the most (`which.max`) frequent value (`table` creates the frequency vector for that variable).